# SAS to SQL Conversion (or Python if easier)

Tags: python, pyspark, sas, databricks

I am performing a conversion of code from SAS to Databricks (which uses PySpark dataframes and/or SQL). For background, I have written code in SAS that essentially takes values from specific columns within a table and places them into new columns for 12 instances.

For a basic example, if PX_fl_PN = 1, then for 12 months after that first event, it will place 1 into the PN column for 12 months. It will iterate over this logic for all 15 columns, and also produce a stacking effect for any new instance of PX_fl_PN within the same 12-month period as the last instance. [For visual reference, check out this sample table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93wPc.png).

Here is the SAS code that does this operation:

```
data pxrx_tot2;
    set out2204.pxrx_tot_v2;
    array X (15) PX_fl_1--PX_fl_13 PX_fl_TPN PX_fl_HYD;
    array ct (15) PN TPN_T TPN_1 TPN_2 TPN_3 TPN_4 TPN_5 TPN_6 TPN_7 TPN_8 TPN_9 TPN_10 TPN_11 TPN HYD;
    do i = 1 to 15;
        ct[i] = x[i] + lag1(x[i]) + lag2(x[i])+ lag3(x[i])+ lag4(x[i])+ lag5(x[i])+ lag6(x[i])+ lag7(x[i])+ lag8(x[i])+ lag9(x[i])+ lag10(x[i])+ lag11(x[i]);
    end;
run;
```

If anyone can help translate this code to SQL or Python, that'd be greatly appreciated!

I have tried multiple different variations of SQL and Python to try and iterate through, and it either results in an error or doesn't produce the correct results.

Comment: The data in your photograph does not look anything like the data your SAS code is expecting as input.  Show some example input data (as text not pictures) and the desired result for that input.

Comment: You're better off reframing this question to use Python or PySpark native code rather than conversion. PySpark/Python has methods for lag operations and summarization as well via matrix logic that may make this easier than SAS does.

Comment: please add a basic sample of input and desired output of the process.

Answer (score 1):

what the SAS code does is - for each column, it sums the current value and last 11 months' values, or prior 11 records in your case, to create a new column.

SAS is tracking what to use and what to create using array indices. you could create a dictionary of source column to target column mapping for the same in python.

```py
# short example
source_target_dict = {
    'px_fl_1': 'tpn_1',
    'px_fl_2': 'tpn_2',
    'px_fl_3': 'tpn_3',
    'px_fl_4': 'tpn_4',
    'px_fl_5': 'tpn_5'
}
```

then use the actual logic to code in pyspark - sum of all values from current row to 11 preceding rows. *It's a window!*

here's an example

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime, random

# create mock data
data_ls = [
    ('1000', datetime.datetime(2020,1,1)+relativedelta(months=i), *[random.randint(0,1) for k in range(5)])
    for i in range(20)
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    toDF(['id', 'dt', 'px_fl_1', 'px_fl_2', 'px_fl_3', 'px_fl_4', 'px_fl_5'])

# use the `source_target_dict` to create new columns using the sum window logic
data_sdf. \
    select('*', 
           *[func.sum(k[0]).over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('dt').rowsBetween(-11, 0)).alias(k[1]) for k in source_target_dict.items()]
           ). \
    show()

# +----+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
# |  id|                 dt|px_fl_1|px_fl_2|px_fl_3|px_fl_4|px_fl_5|tpn_1|tpn_2|tpn_3|tpn_4|tpn_5|
# +----+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
# |1000|2020-01-01 00:00:00|      1|      1|      0|      0|      0|    1|    1|    0|    0|    0|
# |1000|2020-02-01 00:00:00|      0|      1|      1|      1|      0|    1|    2|    1|    1|    0|
# |1000|2020-03-01 00:00:00|      0|      0|      1|      1|      1|    1|    2|    2|    2|    1|
# |1000|2020-04-01 00:00:00|      0|      0|      0|      1|      0|    1|    2|    2|    3|    1|
# |1000|2020-05-01 00:00:00|      0|      0|      1|      1|      1|    1|    2|    3|    4|    2|
# |1000|2020-06-01 00:00:00|      1|      0|      0|      1|      1|    2|    2|    3|    5|    3|
# |1000|2020-07-01 00:00:00|      0|      1|      0|      1|      0|    2|    3|    3|    6|    3|
# |1000|2020-08-01 00:00:00|      0|      0|      1|      0|      1|    2|    3|    4|    6|    4|
# |1000|2020-09-01 00:00:00|      1|      0|      1|      0|      1|    3|    3|    5|    6|    5|
# |1000|2020-10-01 00:00:00|      0|      1|      1|      0|      1|    3|    4|    6|    6|    6|
# |1000|2020-11-01 00:00:00|      1|      0|      1|      0|      1|    4|    4|    7|    6|    7|
# |1000|2020-12-01 00:00:00|      1|      1|      0|      0|      1|    5|    5|    7|    6|    8|
# |1000|2021-01-01 00:00:00|      0|      0|      1|      0|      1|    4|    4|    8|    6|    9|
# |1000|2021-02-01 00:00:00|      0|      1|      0|      1|      0|    4|    4|    7|    6|    9|
# |1000|2021-03-01 00:00:00|      1|      1|      0|      0|      1|    5|    5|    6|    5|    9|
# |1000|2021-04-01 00:00:00|      1|      0|      0|      0|      0|    6|    5|    6|    4|    9|
# |1000|2021-05-01 00:00:00|      0|      0|      1|      0|      1|    6|    5|    6|    3|    9|
# |1000|2021-06-01 00:00:00|      1|      0|      0|      0|      1|    6|    5|    6|    2|    9|
# |1000|2021-07-01 00:00:00|      0|      1|      1|      0|      0|    6|    5|    7|    1|    9|
# |1000|2021-08-01 00:00:00|      0|      1|      1|      0|      0|    6|    6|    7|    1|    8|
# +----+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

---

the list comprehension would result in the following statements

```py
[func.sum(k[0]).over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('dt').rowsBetween(-11, 0)).alias(k[1]) for k in source_target_dict.items()]

# [Column<'sum(px_fl_1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt ASC NULLS FIRST ROWS BETWEEN -11 FOLLOWING AND CURRENT ROW) AS tpn_1'>,
#  Column<'sum(px_fl_2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt ASC NULLS FIRST ROWS BETWEEN -11 FOLLOWING AND CURRENT ROW) AS tpn_2'>,
#  Column<'sum(px_fl_3) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt ASC NULLS FIRST ROWS BETWEEN -11 FOLLOWING AND CURRENT ROW) AS tpn_3'>,
#  Column<'sum(px_fl_4) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt ASC NULLS FIRST ROWS BETWEEN -11 FOLLOWING AND CURRENT ROW) AS tpn_4'>,
#  Column<'sum(px_fl_5) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt ASC NULLS FIRST ROWS BETWEEN -11 FOLLOWING AND CURRENT ROW) AS tpn_5'>]
```